# How to model a double transfer function in Simulink?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, matlab, transfer-function, simulink

I'm trying to model an actuator in Simulink based transfer functions previously derived.

One of functions is $$\omega_p=G_2(K_cG_1V_c-c)$$ where $$G_1=\frac{K_e}{\tau_es+1}$$ $$G_2=\frac{1}{c+K_cK_wG_1}$$

where $K_c,K_w,K_e,c,\tau$ are constants. I'm not really sure what it means to have a transfer function inside another and how to model it. We tried substituting $G_1$ into $G_2$ directly but the result didn't seem right. Would really appreciate if someone could explain what it means, how to model it in Simulink or point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Update: The other part of our system seemed to have been the one causing problems instead of the transfer functions it turned out.

Comment: Please add some information regarding the transfer functions. What is $G_1, G_2, \omega_p $ ? What’s the transfer function of the actuator ? It would be best if you edit the question and add this information.

Comment: if substituting $G_1$ into $G_2$ didnt gave the right result, you have either made a mistake substituting or your model description is off. Converting this to a block diagram is equal to substituting the equations into a single transfer function.

Comment: It could be a composition of elementary transfer functions. Try to write down the block diagram of your system.